# Frama-c cannot prove loop implemented by goto

Tags: c, frama-c

- Env: 24.0 (Chromium)
- Command: frama-c -wp -wp-legacy xx.c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int r;
/*@
  requires \valid_read(a + (0 .. length-1)) && length > 0;
  assigns r;
  ensures \forall size_t off ; 0 <= off < length ==> a[off] != r;
*/
void notin(int* a, size_t length) {
  int result = 0;
  int max = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  
assign_part:
  if (a[i] >= max) {
    max = a[i];
  }
  result = max + 1;
  i = i + 1;
 
  if (i < length) {
    goto assign_part;
  }

  r = result;
}
```

The error message says:

```
[kernel] Parsing goto_test/while_2_goto_version.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] goto_test/while_2_goto_version.c:14: Warning: 
  Missing assigns clause (assigns 'everything' instead)
[wp] 6 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo ] Goal typed_notin_assigns_part2 : Timeout (Qed:4ms) (10s)
[wp] Proved goals:    5 / 6
  Qed:             4  (3ms-10ms-30ms)
  Alt-Ergo :       1  (6ms) (44) (interrupted: 1)
[wp] goto_test/while_2_goto_version.c:8: Warning: 
  Memory model hypotheses for function 'notin':
  /*@ behavior wp_typed:
        requires \separated(a + (..), &r
```

The equivalent code implemented with while loop which can be proved by `frama-c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int r;
/*@
  requires \valid_read(a + (0 .. length-1)) && length > 0;
  assigns r;
  ensures \forall size_t off ; 0 <= off < length ==> a[off] != r;
*/
void notin(int* a, size_t length) {
 int result = 0;
 int max = 0;
 size_t i = 0;
 
 /*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= length;
   @ loop invariant \forall size_t j; 0 <= j < i ==> a[j] <= max;
   @ loop invariant \forall size_t k; 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] != result;
   @ loop assigns i, result, max;
 */
 while (i < length) {
   if (a[i] >= max) {
     max = a[i];
   }
   result = max + 1;
   i = i + 1;
 }

 r = result;
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is *why* are you using `goto` here?

Comment: @Shawn Hi Shawn, there are some code I want to prove with frama-c, and goto statements are already there that I cannot change. So I want to do some test at first. As you may already know, the code in my question can be replaced by a while loop indeed.

Comment: @Lebecca it should be used as an example of "how to do not write code in C".  No `return` value - global variable used instead, goto instead of loops. What is the goal of those tests?

Comment: @gulpr Hi gulpr, the goal here is to prove that after the execution, this will be satisfied `ensures \forall size_t off ; 0 <= off < length ==> a[off] != r;`, which means the value of r is not the same as any other element in the input array.

Comment: If `a[i]` is `INT_MAX` you get the signed integer overflow `max + 1`, i.e. UB.

Comment: Hi 273k, @273K, as `integer` is used in the specification, the `frama-c` will take it as ideal natural numbers and thus no overflow issue exists here.

You can see my updated question giving the `while loop` version code, which can be proved by `frama-c`.

Comment: I can only guess `frama-c` does not recognize semantical loops. It assumes `i < length` is false and `a[i]` is not iterated completely.

Comment: try porting the loop invariants as `// @assert` clauses. The purpose of loop invariants is allowing to replace a loop with a set of "assertions" that are sustained by a given loop.

Comment: @tstanisl Hi tstanisl. Thanks for your suggestions! I tested and all the `asserts` converted from `loop invariants` can be proved. One more thing I find is that the `ensure` is precisely guaranteed (if I change it to an incorrect predicate then there will be one more failed `goal`), so there seems no need to add those `asserts` to support the `ensure`. The failed goal is related to `assigns_part2`, which seems to be related to the `assigns r;` I cannot find a way for `frama-c` to recognize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Frama-C 23, the support of loops implemented using `gotos` (called "non-natural loops") has been removed. Mainly because it was probably wrong in the old WP engine. This is a known limitation that is listed in the manual of WP (Section 1.6):

https://frama-c.com/download/wp-manual-28.0-Nickel.pdf

Adding this support in the new WP engine is possible but requires substantial work.

Now, what are the problems here. First, the property that it not proved is the global `assigns` property. The reason why it is not proved is that when the old WP engine finds that there is a loop with `goto`, it considers that it assigns everything (which is more than just `r`). One would have to provide an `assigns` specification for the loop. However, after diving into the code of the engine, I am pretty sure that there is no way to provide such a specification for a loop with gotos.

Second, to prove a code that contains a loop, WP needs a suitable invariant. Here, we have no "classic" loop, thus one cannot provide a `loop invariant`, we should thus use a generalized invariant:

```
L:
  //@ invariant ...
  foo();
goto L;
```

However, again, this is not supported in the WP engines (both the old and the new one).

Comment: Hi Ksass, that is the reason why I use `frama-c -wp -wp-legacy` here. If I use `frama-c -wp`, `frama-c` will tells me `non-natural loops` are not supported directly. I want to know how the `wp` buggy version works, even though it is built with unsoundness bugs.

Comment: I had a closer look to the old engine, but the code is complex, so I might have missed details. I have completed the answer for the old engine. If you really want to dive into those details, this branch: https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/tree/stable/chromium is the right one, in `src/plugins/wp`, the right files are CfgCompiler, Cil2Cfg, wpAnnot and wpStrategy. But honestly, I don't know if it worth the time. The paper on which the goto treatment is based is "Tao Wei, Jian Mao, Wei Zou, and Yu Chen. A New Algorithm for Identifying Loops in Decompilation", reading it might be more useful.